# Only show YUI autocomplete footer when there are 5 results

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui, yui-autocomplete

I would like the autocomplete to display a footer which says `Displaying top 5 results` only when there are 5 results actually being displayed.

So far, I have it set up so that it won't display if at first there are less than 5 results, but once 5 results have been loaded the footer always displays, regardless of how many results are actually being displayed.

Please excuse the silly `flip` gimmick.

```
oAC.formatResult = function(oResultData, sQuery, sResultMatch) {
         var sKey = sResultMatch

         // Extract the part of the match that the user did not type
         var sKeyRemainder = sKey.substr(sQuery.length);


         oAC.setFooter("");
         var aMarkup = ["<div class='myCustomResult'>",
                             "<span style='font-weight:bold'>",
                             sQuery,
                             "</span>",
                             sKeyRemainder,
                             "<br>",
                             "</div>"];

         if (oResultData[2] >= 4) {
            flip = true;
         }
         if (flip) {
            oAC.setFooter("<div style=\"margin-left:5px;\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">See more results for " + sQuery + "</span><br>Showing top 5 results</div>");
         }
         return (aMarkup.join(""));
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set it in the `formatResult` function, I tried using the `doBeforeExpandContainer` function, and it works like a charm.

```
oAC.formatResult = function(oResultData, sQuery, sResultMatch) {
   var sKey = sResultMatch

   // Extract the part of the match that the user did not type
   var sKeyRemainder = sKey.substr(sQuery.length);


   oAC.setFooter("");
   var aMarkup = ["<div class='myCustomResult'>",
                       "<span style='font-weight:bold'>",
                       sQuery,
                       "</span>",
                       sKeyRemainder,
                       "<br>",
                       "</div>"];

   oAC.setFooter("<div class=\"ac-footer\"><div class=\"ac-footer-content\"><a class=\"ac-footer-link\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"spandex(this,event,'filter-company');return false;\">See more results for <b>" + sQuery + "</b></a><br><span class=\"ac-footer-sub\">Showing top 5 results</span></div></div>");

   return (aMarkup.join(""));
};

oAC.doBeforeExpandContainer = function(sQuery, oResponse) {
   if (oAC._nDisplayedItems <= 5) {
      oAC.setFooter("");
   }

   return true;
}
```

`doBeforeExpandContainer` is called every time the container opens (just as you would expect it to) and `_nDisplayedItems` is how many items are going to be displayed in the list (also as you would expect).

So when results are retrieved, the footer is added every time. Then, before the box shows, if there are five or less results, the footer is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You want the footer to only appear when there are 5 results?

Then shouldn't you change

```
if (oResultData[2] >= 4) {
    flip = true;
}
```

To

```
if (oResultData[2] == 4) {  // is this a zero based number? or should this be 5?
    flip = true;
}
else { flip = false } // assuming you don't already reset this in scope
```

?

Comment: Yeah, this is one variation of the many similar routes I've tried. If the formatResult function was called up every time the autocomplete is displayed, this would work. However, it is only called when the results are retrieved. So with this logic, if you type in a letter and get more than 5 results, the footer will show up. Then when you type in more letters, the number of results diminishes. once you get down to less than 5, the footer should disappear. However, since the result has already been retrieved, this function isn't called and the footer remains unaffected.